# Error: Expected a value of type 'Uri', but got one of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get a string from a flash server hosted in my machine at the press of a button on a flutter app, so the text will change to the flask string each time the button is pressed.
flask server:
[image: Text]

flutter app:

[image: Text]

When I press the button I would expect to get the new string, but get the error of my question title, I'm aware I that is a "type" error, but not sure where I'm giving that 'String' value, so how to fix my code?
Any help is appreciated !

full error if it helps: https://textuploader.com/tdhk0

Here is my flutter code(request.dart and main.dar):

````
//request dart-------------------------

import 'package:http/http.dart';

Future getData(url) async {
  Response response = await get(url);
  return response.body;
}
//main.dart-------------------------------

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:passg/request.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('Change Text Dynamically on Button Click')
            ),
            body: Center(
                child: UpdateText()
            )
        )
    );
  }
}

class UpdateText extends StatefulWidget {

  UpdateTextState createState() => UpdateTextState();

}

class UpdateTextState extends State {

  String textHolder = 'Old Sample Text...!!!';

  changeText() async {
    var data = await getData('http://10.0.2.2:5000/passg');
    var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);
    setState(() {
      textHolder = decodedData;
    });

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 20),
                  child: Text('$textHolder',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21))),

              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => changeText(),
                child: Text('Click Here To Change Text Widget Text Dynamically'),
              ),

            ]))
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 5):

The source of your problems comes from missing type on parameters. By doing so the parameters becomes `dynamic` which makes it impossible for the Dart analyzer to identify potential type problems before running your application. You should therefore always specify types explicit when it comes to signatures of methods and class fields.

The problem is this method:

```
Future getData(url) async {
  Response response = await get(url);
  return response.body;
}
```

The `url` parameter should be of the `Uri` type if you want to do this. Alternative, you can make it `String` but you then need to parse that `String` into a `Uri` like this:

```
Future getData(String url) async {
  Response response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
  return response.body;
}
```

You can read the documentation of the `get()` method, from the `http` package, to see it expect an `Uri`: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client/get.html

Comment: Thanks, not sure if it worked since still won't do what I'm expecting, I get a completely different error this time : Error: XMLHttpRequest error.

Comment: For the same reasons it would be ideal to also specify that the return type is a `Future<String>`.

Answer (score 5):

Try creating your url this way :

```dart
var data = await getData(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:5000/passg'));
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure if it worked since still won't do what I'm expecting, I get a completely different error this time : Error: XMLHttpRequest error.

Comment: Yes it worked, this "new" error has to do with the CORS policy of your API.